# Reading a 2D array of pointers to a class

Tags: c++, sdl

I am designing a very simply video game to help learn to use SDL. I have encountered a problem with collision detection. In order to draw the game map (using tiles) I create, in a class called `Map`, a 2D array of pointers to a class called `Tile`. The `Map` class has a function called `set_tiles` that defines all of the tiles by reading them from a `.MAP` file. I also have a class called `Hero`, which contains all of the functions and variables about the hero. All very trivial. However, when I try and read the array from anywhere else it produces strange results (through bug testing I found that the x and y values are thousands off, but I may have made a mistake there). Here's the code.

```
SDL_Surface* Map::set_tiles ( SDL_Surface* tile_image ) {

Setup setup;

//Make a temporary map to draw the tiles to
Uint32 rmask, gmask, bmask, amask;
if ( SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN ) {
    rmask = 0x00000000;
    gmask = 0x00000000;
    bmask = 0x00000000;
    amask = 0x00000000;
}
else {
    rmask = 0x00000000;
    gmask = 0x00000000;
    bmask = 0x00000000;
    amask = 0x00000000;
}
SDL_Surface* temp_map = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE, MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT, 32, rmask, gmask, bmask, amask);

//Open the map
std::ifstream map ( "Test.map" );

//Catch any errors
if ( map.fail() ) return NULL;

//Initialize the tiles
for ( int y = 0; y < MAP_HEIGHT / TILE_HEIGHT; y++ ) {
    for ( int x = 0; x < MAP_WIDTH / TILE_WIDTH; x++ ) {
        //Determines the tile type
        int tile_type = -1;

        //Read the tile type from the map
        map >> tile_type;

        //Make sure it's a real tile
        if ( tile_type < 0 || tile_type >= TILE_SPRITES ) {
            map.close();
            return NULL;
        }

        //Error check for the .map file
        if ( map.fail() ) {
            map.close();
            return NULL;
        }

        //Add the tile to the array
        tile_array[x][y] = &Tile ( x, y, tile_type );

        //Create the temp. image crop
        SDL_Rect* temp_crop = &tile_array[x][y]->get_crop();

        //Edit the temp. map
        setup.apply_surface ( x * TILE_WIDTH, y * TILE_HEIGHT, tile_image, temp_map, temp_crop );
    }

}

map.close();

//Return the modified map
return temp_map;

}
```

Now, if I try to read it somewhere else, I have a problem. I.E.

```
bool Hero::collision_check ( Map map ) {
for ( int y = 0; y < MAP_HEIGHT / TILE_HEIGHT; y++ ) {
    for ( int x = 0; x < MAP_WIDTH / TILE_WIDTH; x++ ) {
        Tile* tile = map.tile_array[x][y];
        if ( collision ( box, tile->get_box() ) ) {
            //Switch the effect based on the tile type
            switch ( tile->get_type() ) {
            case TILE_RED:
            case TILE_GREEN:
            case TILE_BLUE:
                return false;
                break;
            case TILE_CENTER:
            case TILE_TOP:
            case TILE_TOPRIGHT:
            case TILE_RIGHT:
            case TILE_BOTTOMRIGHT:
            case TILE_BOTTOM:
            case TILE_BOTTOMLEFT:
            case TILE_LEFT:
            case TILE_TOPLEFT:
                return true;
                break;
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
return false;
}
```

I'm not a master when it comes to pointers (or most other things). Are there any obvious flaws that would explain my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line

```
tile_array[x][y] = &Tile ( x, y, tile_type );
```

you are assigning the address of a temporary to your vector. As soon as that expression ends, the temporary is destroyed and the pointer you saved now points to an invalid object. Instead of storing pointers to Tile object, I would store the tile objects themselves in `tile_array`.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a pointer to a temporary that goes out of scope:

```
 tile_array[x][y] = &Tile ( x, y, tile_type );
```

You are probably looking for

```
 tile_array[x][y] = new Tile ( x, y, tile_type );
```

PS1: That if statement at the top doesn't seem very useful

PS2: next time it'd help if you post a minimal example rather than all your code -- people tend to ignore posts with too much code to read through

EDIT:

What you're doing is basically:

```
Foo* fp;
// a Foo() is created, its address assigned to fp,
// but it is then destroyed at the end of the statement
fp = &Foo(2);
// now fp is a pointer to unallocated memory and using it causes undefined behaviour
fp.val; // this value is now undefined
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive, I don't even understand why that's a problem or how to fix it.